# Efficiently Retrieving the Last Value of 'sim' Array in Python Without Using a Loop

Tags: python, numpy

I hope you're doing well. I'm currently working on a Python script that involves generating Poisson-distributed random variables and using them to create an array of uniformly distributed random variables.

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)
for i in range(1000000):
    # Generate Poisson-distributed random variable
    f = np.random.poisson(100)
    # Generate uniformly distributed random variables based on 'f'
    sim = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size = f)
```

My question is: how can I efficiently retrieve the last value of the `sim` array without using a loop? I want to avoid unnecessary iterations for better performance.

I am expecting sim at the last iteration to be:

```
sim = array([0.1972752 , 0.69386029, 0.16064322, 0.21875956, 0.63476699,
       0.26683404, 0.63378383, 0.31111131, 0.21664078, 0.64273178,
       0.78534717, 0.90744546, 0.65749617, 0.82766704, 0.96122804,
       0.87250394, 0.89164427, 0.19575007, 0.4075956 , 0.18429471,
       0.77595282, 0.67349085, 0.51108008, 0.68602884, 0.52195242,
       0.4552027 , 0.27281105, 0.03650892, 0.74087079, 0.9616082 ,
       0.56050948, 0.38289145, 0.63187262, 0.48926304, 0.5659105 ,
       0.95817986, 0.73017458, 0.21787125, 0.30557385, 0.55442776,
       0.41365291, 0.15506145, 0.24283196, 0.1863222 , 0.73490832,
       0.32895835, 0.74733175, 0.09413532, 0.32777647, 0.19247969,
       0.52469494, 0.12492405, 0.33497356, 0.98037802, 0.8359363 ,
       0.51449289, 0.35795273, 0.75508642, 0.39085891, 0.41239322,
       0.45844823, 0.75392863, 0.13213636, 0.29979253, 0.33939816,
       0.76370558, 0.45348   , 0.94515004, 0.95332925, 0.28357461,
       0.43903746, 0.70223586, 0.96290664, 0.14575737, 0.52867102,
       0.17841445, 0.72974685, 0.48183649, 0.13601802, 0.61254081,
       0.92676118, 0.43280852, 0.63369342, 0.7611695 , 0.57064143,
       0.55556153, 0.65950395, 0.58653741, 0.97805968, 0.44232296,
       0.2526144 , 0.4380003 , 0.00972133, 0.93934947, 0.51280434,
       0.50173942, 0.71748328, 0.49256255, 0.40028602, 0.70097581,
       0.2200894 , 0.52618643])
```

Comment: To get the last value of any array you can simply use negative indexing (counting from the end): `last = sim[-1]`. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @OskarHofmann I fixed the code formatting. Hidden was the 1 million loops and I assume they meant they want the sim result from the 1 millionth iteration.

Comment: Jared, you are correct. i want sim from 100000 iteration. without using loop.

Comment: Do you "always" want to skip of having run this once to get the final value do you want to reapply the state to get the value again similar to how one might use a seed?

Comment: correct. the aim here is get get last sim, without computing sim for i=1,2,3,....99999. only compute i=1000000. this will optimise speed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot. While it is possible to advance the state of the random number generator by n draws, you do not know how many draws you would need as the number of uniform numbers you draw depends on the numbers drawn from the Poisson distribution. And each random-function can actually use more than one draw to generate their output.

Without any apriori assumptions of the random number generators or a fixed seed, this number is not known until you keep drawing the corresponding numbers from the random-number-generators.

Of course we are dealing with pseudo-random-numbers here so one COULD look up the maths behind the used generators and calculate (for a given seed) the number of draws, but I do not think that this is the direction you want to go.

Is there a special reason why you want to achieve this? Maybe one can achieve the same goal using statistics or math or a different function.

Comment: Thanks, the reason is when lamb (e.g f = np.random.poisson(lamb = 100000)) get too large the simulation because very slow, while im am interested in the last sim.

Comment: Why are you intereseted in the last sim though? Statistically, it is the same as every other sim.